# Include Apple's SimplePing (Objective-C) in Qt C++ Project

Tags: c++, objective-c, qt

ICMP ping for MacOS is not possible with Qt, because it would require raw sockets. There is however a SimplePing Objective-C code available from Apple, and a SimplePingHelper from Chris Hulbert:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SimplePing/Listings/Common_SimplePing_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000716-Common_SimplePing_m-DontLinkElementID_4
- http://www.splinter.com.au/how-to-ping-a-server-in-objective-c-iphone/
- https://github.com/chrishulbert/SimplePingHelper

My problem is that this is Objective-C, and not Objective-C++, and to use it with Qt I would need to wrap it into an Objective-C++ class where the header is pure C++ and the Objective-C/C++ SimplePing code in the .mm implementation of that class.

Although I managed to include other Objective-C++ code in Qt projects, I'm stuck with this.

(Alternatively, to use QProcess to run Ping is not desired, the overhead is too big for the volume of pings needed here.)

Comment: Step 1; create minimal C program which uses the Objective C stuff. Step 2. Create a plain C++ program which uses it. Step 3. Integrate result of Step 2 into your Qt project.

Comment: *"to use it with Qt I would need to wrap it into an Objective-C++ class"*, I don't know Mac peculiarities, but why?

Comment: @hyde: I cannot include Objective C (.m) into a Qt C++ project directly. However Objective C++ (.mm) can get included, as long as it's header file is pure C++, not Objective C++.

Comment: @hyde: "Step 3" is not a problem, "Step 2" will not work as long as a header file (.h) still contains Objective C / Objective C++. That's where I'm stuck, convert the objective header files to pure C / C++.

Comment: If you have a header file compatible with plain C, it is usually trivial to use it from C++ too. If it uses the few incompatible things, then you have to edit it by hand to fix those. The question doesn't really have enough details to give complete answer, but generally wrap any C *declarations* inside `extern "C" {};` block. Most library header files do this by default with `#ifdef` for C++ compliation. Also note, if compiled with C++ compiler, it's still C++ code then, but calling convention will be C compatible (no symbol name mangling for example).

Comment: Important thing to realize about C/C++ preprosessor stuff, including `#include`, is that it is just text which gets "copy-pasted" where it is included. There is no "hidden magic" or some special "modules", it's just text which you could paste or write by hand instead of using `#include` for example.

Comment: "If you have a header file compatible with plain C" - unfortunately not. As you say, that would have been easy. However they are Objective C. Sourcecode is in the links listed in the question.

Comment: If you can do the step 1 I suggest above, how do you do that without having a C-compatible header file?

Comment: @hyde: That's exactly my problem, I have to modify the objective C code of Apple's SimplePing, move all Objective C to a .mm file, build an Objective C++ class from it, and create a pure C++ header file, and I do not know enough Objective C to do that - that's my problem, that's where I need help.